# Limit of ratio of successive n-nacci numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, fibonacci-numbers

The n-nacci numbers are defined as
$${}_nF_k  = {}_nF_{k - 1} + {}_nF_{k - 2} + \cdots + {}_nF_{k - n + 1}$$

Now, it's pretty well-known that the limit of successive $2$-nacci numbers (i.e. the Fibonacci numbers) is equal to $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {F_{n+1} \over F{n}} = \phi = \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$$.

How would one find the limiting ratio of the tribonacci numbers? And how can that be generalized to the n-nacci numbers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could be interested by the following link
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fibonaccin-StepNumber.html

What they essentially show is that the limit of the ratio is the solution of the equation $$x^n(2-x)=1$$ For tribonacci numbers, $x$ is given by $$\frac{1}{3} \left(1+\sqrt[3]{19-3 \sqrt{33}}+\sqrt[3]{19+3 \sqrt{33}}\right)=1.83929$$ For tetranacci numbers, we start with the ugly formula,

$$x =\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{z}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{11}{4}-z+\frac{13}{4\sqrt{z}}}$$

where,

$$z = \tfrac{11}{12}-\tfrac{1}{3}\left(\tfrac{65+3\sqrt{1689}}{2}\right)^{1/3}+\tfrac{1}{3}\left(\tfrac{-65+3\sqrt{1689}}{2}\right)^{1/3}$$

and which is $x=1.92756\dots$. If $n$ increases, the limit of the ratio is $2$.

For high orders, the solution of the equation can be approximated using Newton method starting at $x=2$ and the first iterate is simply $(2-2^{-n})$ which is $1.9375$ for tetranacci numbers. A better approximation is $(2-2^{-n}-2^{-2 n-1} n)$ which gives $1.92969$.

Going to higher order of Newton method, we can approximate still better using $$x \simeq 2+\frac{1}{\frac{(n+1) n}{2^{n+3}-4 n}+\frac{n}{2}-2^n}$$ which gives $1.84049$ for tribonacci numbers and $1.92765$ for tetranacci numbers.

Continuing the work, I found that this limit could be accurately represented by $$x \simeq 2-\exp\left({0.0965617 -0.73092 n+\frac{0.80957}{n}}\right)$$

**Edit** *six years later !*

Back to the problem (almost by accident), I found a rather better *approximation*
$$x\sim 2+\frac{1 }{\frac{n}{2}+\frac{\left(3\ 2^n-n+1\right) (n+1) n}{3 \left(n^2-\left(2^{n+3}+1\right) n+2^{2
   n+3}\right)}-2^n } $$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 2 & 1.6250000000000000000 &  1.6180339887498948482 \\
 3 & 1.8394879369768586903 &  1.8392867552141611326 \\
 4 & 1.9275687815833801235 &  1.9275619754829253043 \\
 5 & 1.9659485002996453378 &  1.9659482366454853372 \\
 6 & 1.9835828545045254017 &  1.9835828434243263304 \\
 7 & 1.9919641970897590225 &  1.9919641966050350211 \\
 8 & 1.9960311797568978058 &  1.9960311797354145898 \\
 9 & 1.9980294702632357105 &  1.9980294702622866987 \\
 10 & 1.9990186327101425508 &  1.9990186327101011387 \\
 11 & 1.9995104019782872690 &  1.9995104019782854914 \\
 12 & 1.9997555009373176116 &  1.9997555009373175367 \\
 13 & 1.9998778327115455431 &  1.9998778327115455400 \\
 14 & 1.9999389387495946486 &  1.9999389387495946486
\end{array}
\right)$$ For $n \geq 14$, the first twenty figures are exact.

Comment: I had never noticed this answer, sorry.

Comment: You are welcome ! This was a very interesting problem. Cheers.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: I modified your tetranacci formula a bit. I hope it's ok. :)

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII. Thank you ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I just calculated 10,000 digits of many higher order naccis. Here is the link: http://www.genautica.com/math/naccis/fibonacci_and_higher_order_naccis.html (bottom of page).

Answer (score 1):

The usual solution to [recurrence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation) works here.  Find the characteristic polynomial and its greatest root(s) in absolute value.  Here you have $a_k=a_{k-1}+a_{k-2}+\dots+a_{k-n}$ so the polynomial is $x^n=\frac {x^n-1}{x-1}$

Comment: Can't we prove it in a way similar to the $x = 1 + 1/x$ proof that is used for the Fibonacci case?

Comment: I don't think so.  As the degree gets higher, solving polynomials gets hard.  5 and above are (usually and I think here) impossible in radicals.  You can get a numerical solution easily.

Comment: Could you point me to how I could do the $n = 3$ case algebraically?

Comment: Any cubic can be solved by [Cardano's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardano%27s_formula#Cardano.27s_method) You have $x^3=x^2+x+1$  I didn't say it was easy, and the fourth degree is much worse.

Answer (score 1):

Denote the limiting ratio of $n$-nacci numbers as $\,a_n.\,$ A
standard result is that $\,a_n\,$ is a root of a polynomial equation.
More precisely, define

$$ f_n(x) := x^{n} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = \frac{g_n(x)}{x-1} \tag1 $$

where

$$ g_n(x) := 1 - (2 -x)x^n \tag2 $$

by expanding $\,f_n(x)(x-1)\,$ as a telescoping sum
simplifying to $\,g_n (x).\,$

The result is that $a_n$ is the largest real root of $\,f_n(x) = 0.\,$

Assuming that $\,x \ne 1\,$ then $\,f_n(x) = 0\,$ iff
$\,g_n(x) = 0.\,$

Assuming that $\,x \ne 2\,$ then $\,g_n(x) = 0\,$ iff
$\,x = 2-x^{-n}.\,$

Assuming that $\,n>1\,$ then $\,f_n(1) = 1 - n < 0\,$
and $\,f_n(2) = g_n(2) = 1 > 0.\,$

Thus, by the intermediate value theorem there exists
$\,1 < a_n < 2\,$ such that $\,f_n(a_n) = 0.\,$

Now, since $\,a_n = 2 - a_n^{-n},\,$ this implies that
$\,a_n\to 2$ but is there a better result? Yes.

Define

$$ b_n := \frac{2^{-n}+2-a_n}2 = h_n(2^{-n-1}) \tag3 $$

where

$$ h_n(z) := 2z + z\sum_{k=1}^\infty c_n(k) \frac{z^k}{k!} \tag4 $$

and

$$ c_n(k) := n \prod_{j=1}^{k-1} j+n+k\,n. \tag5 $$