# Research the roots of complex equation $x^n(x-2) = 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to prove that only one of roots of equation $ x^n(x-2) = 1 \:n>1 $ is lying outside unit circle. By researching how function on the left behave on real line i have found that root exists between 2 and 3. Then i tried really hard to imagine how function $ x^n $ looks like and how multiplying on $ x-2 $ or even $x - n$ would deform it but still no luck at it and I had spent on it so much time that I simply can't spend any more. The only "results" i had got are something trivial, like multiplying on $x-n$ will compress values inside unit circle centered at n. So, I'm yet again asking for your help and tips.

Comment: See the detailed solution using Rouché's theorem by Plasma Vortex in https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1760639p11509114

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sufficiently small $\epsilon$, by Rouche's theorem, since $|z^{n+1}-1|\lt|2z^n|$, it has $n$ zeros in the disc $|z|=1+\epsilon$, and hence letting $\epsilon\to0$, in the unit disc.

See "Rouché's theorem - Wikipedia" https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem

Comment: Chris ,you could also have provided a brief note regarding Rouche's theorem in your answer

Comment: @JordanLawson at your behest, I have provided a link.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I believe this little edit has made your post complete and will cater to the needs of other in future.

Comment: Funnily, there is a connection with the so-called "tribonacci numbers" (generalization of the Fibonacci numbers) : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723008.

Comment: If $z$ is such that a $z^{n+1}=-1$, then, $|z|=1$ and $|z^{n+1}-1|=|2z^n|$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I have tried to rectify this by considering a slightly larger disc and taking limits.

Comment: But now the equality $2=|2z^n|$ doesn't hold.

Comment: Right. @JoséCarlosSantos missed that.  The estimate $2(1+\epsilon)^n\gt(1+\epsilon)^{n+1}+1$ should work though.