# Convergence of a sequence of polynomial roots

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

Consider $a_{n}$ the sequence formed by the positive real roots of the following polynomial equation:

$$x^{n} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = 0$$

Prove that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_{n} = 2$.

I have no idea on how to start the question, can anyone give me some tips?

You can also see the question as this:

If $c_{n}$ is a geometric progression with first term equal to one and positive ratio, then what do I have to do to prove that $2$ is the minimum ratio of $c_{n}$ so that any term of $c_{n}$ is greater than the sum of the preceding terms?

If you take the sequence of powers of $2$, you have:

$(1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024)$

If you pick each term and subtract from it each of the preceding terms, you will have:

$$2-1=1$$

$$4-2-1=1$$

$$8-4-2-1=1$$

$$16-8-4-2-1=1$$
$$\ldots$$
and so on.

When I saw this, I started to think, for no avail up to now, if the $2$ is the least exponential base that, if you take each power and subtract each of the preceding powers, it will remain a positive number?

That what motivated me to ask the question at hand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you looked at a few initial values? Can you show the $a_n$ are bounded?  Without showing any effort at all, you shouldn't  expect others here to guide you.

Comment: Is there any missing information about |x| such as |x|<1?

Comment: @abiessu, Could you please explain how you got your formula. Thanks.

Comment: @Macavity i have tested from n=1 to n=10. For n=10, the positive real root is 1,9999...

Comment: Can you show that$\, x^{n} - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = (1 - (2 -x)x^n)/(x - 1)$?

Comment: @Somos, the issue with this is that it suggests $x=2$ or $x=0$ as the root for any value of $n$, which is really not the case. Not sure why?

Comment: @NoChance My equation is true for **all** $x\ne 1$. Proof uses the sum of a finite geometric series.

Comment: @NoChance Try using $\,\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^{k} = (x^n-1)/(x-1)\,$ instead of $\,-\sum_{k=n}^\infty x^{k}  = x^n/(x-1).$

Comment: I don't agree on closing this question. The question is clear and has not bee answered. There is no obvious values from closing questions that people can't answer!!! If few gurus know how to do it, the rest don't - Should not close this in my opinion. It is not trivial.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of ratio of successive n-nacci numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/722895/limit-of-ratio-of-successive-n-nacci-numbers)

Comment: @Somos Yes, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For positive natural $n$, let $y_{n}$ be the unique positive real root of the equation $$y_{n}^{n}+\dots+y_{n}^{1}\ =\ 1$$ (uniqueness is by the monotonicity in $y_{n}$ of the expression on the left). It’s not hard to see (and is indeed our motivation) that $y_{n}=x_{n}^{-1}$. It’s likewise clear that $$y_{1}\ \geq\  y_{2}\ \geq\ \dots\ \geq\ \tfrac{1}{2}.$$ Moreover, for any $\varepsilon > 0$ and $n\geq-\log_{2}\left(\varepsilon\right)$, $$\left(\tfrac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)^{n}+\dots+\left(\tfrac{1}{2}+\varepsilon\right)^{1}\ \geq\ 1-\left(\tfrac{1}{2}\right)^{n}+\varepsilon\ \geq\ 1$$ so that for all $\varepsilon>0$ and sufficiently (namely in the precise sense above) large $n$, $$\tfrac{1}{2}\ \leq\ y_{n}\ \leq\ \tfrac{1}{2}+\varepsilon.$$ It follows that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(y_{n}\right)\ =\ \tfrac{1}{2}$$ and thus that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(x_{n}\right)\ =\ 2$$ as claimed.

Answer (score 3):

We have $$ x^n - \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x^k = \frac{x^{n+1} - 2 x^n + 1}{x - 1}$$
Let $f_n(x) = x^{n+1} - 2 x^n + 1$.  Show that $f_n(2) = 1$ and, for $n\ge 2$,
$f_n(2 - 1/n) < 0$.